# Xcode bots creation script

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-bots

Is there a way to create and deploy Xcode bots without using Xcode? Is there any script or library that allows bot creation/management/deletion?

Comment: Xcode bots is a bit limited in what it can do as compared to some of the other continuous integration tools out there.  if you don't want to use Xcode maybe you could look into Jenkins of Travis, which do the same thing but have more complexity.  However, with more complexity comes a lot more customization